# Ganache-Cli - getBalance() via web3

Tags: web3js

I am running a local ganache-cli as `ganache-cli -p 8545`.

Furthermore, I created a frontend script using web3:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Dapp</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>This is my balance</h1>
    <button onclick="getBalance()">Update my balance </button>
    <span id="myBalance"></span> in Ether.

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }

        console.log("Log:");
        console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);

        function getBalance() {
            document.getElementById("myBalance").innerText = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]),
                "ether");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The script basically updates my balance which I would have in ether.

However, my `web3.eth.accounts[0]` is `undefined`. See my `console.log` below:

[image]

Any suggestion what might be wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

I added the following to my code:

```
    console.log("Log: (web3.eth)");
    console.log(web3.eth);
    console.log("Log: (web3.eth.accounts)");
    console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that `web3.eth.accounts` is `[]`?

Comment: Which branch of the `if` is being taken here? Are you using an `HttpProvider` or some provider injected into the page (e.g. MetaMask)?

Comment: @smarx `web.eth.accounts` is undefined when executing my code. I am running a ganache locally. Please see my update.

Comment: Your comment says `web.eth.accounts` is undefined (a typo for `web3.eth.accounts`?), but your post says that `web3.eth.accounts[0]` is undefined, which means `web3.eth.accounts` must be defined. I know you're using `ganache-cli`, but I still need to know which branch of the `if` is being taken. If you're not sure, please add logging in each branch so we can find out.

Comment: @smarx I added an update to my question. Basically `web3.eth` has an accounts branch. Any suggestions how to access this?

Comment: If you don't understand a question, please ask for clarification. In the following code, I've marked the two branches of an `if` statement: `if (condition) { console.log("This is the first branch."); } else { console.log("This is the second branch."); }`. In your code, you have an `if` statement, and I need to know which branch is being executed.

Comment: Hi, I too face similar issue. I posted it here (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46556/connecting-to-local-blockchain-using-web3-and-httpprovider), if you know a solution to this , let me know.